# How to copy data from one table to another new table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

When I searched for it I got some answers. But when I am working with this solution- (screenshot attached).

[image]

I am getting error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'

I have a table `student_constraint` and I want to create a new table like `student_constraint`.

```
create table student_info like student_constraint
```

Can you please explain this concept?

Thank you!

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different products with different sql flavours.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be using SQL Server, based on the error message.  You may try using `SELECT ... INTO` syntax:

```
SELECT *
INTO student_info
FROM student_constraint;
```

Note that there are some caviats to this approach, as dicussed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql).  For maximal control, you may consider creating the new table manually using a formal `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Thanks Tim ! can you tell me does SQL server support like statement or not?

Comment: @RaviSolanki You don't need to use `LIKE` here, unless it be part of the `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fast way to copy just data from one table to another new table

```
SELECT * 
INTO student_info 
FROM student_constraint
```

Comment: "Best" is highly debatable. And we now see that OP started another thread wanting an exact duplicate of the table - constraints, indexes, etc.

Comment: @SMor You are right.And this is a fast way to copy just data from one table to another new table

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html - *Use CREATE TABLE ... LIKE to create an empty table based on the definition of another table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the original table:* This is mysql only and not supported by sqlserver.